# ExtJS 4.2.x How do I find the group that the selected grid row is in?

Tags: extjs, grid

In ExtJS 4.2.x I have a grouped grid.  When I re-load the data I attempt to re-select the row that was previously selected.  But I also collapse all groups if there is more than one group.  So, now I have a selected row, but it's hidden because the group is collapsed. I want to expand the group that that row is in.

How do I find the group that the selected row belongs to?

I'd like to avoid any solution that uses CSS classes to determine a parent group as these tend to change on ExtJS major releases.

Edit:
I didn't test this as I found that another developer changed something else and my issue no longer exists. But as an intellectual exercise... This seems to be a decent solution. It may not perform well with many records. And with forEach there isn't a way to short circuit the checks once the correct group is found.

Any better (more performant) solutions out there?

```
// where this = store
if (this.isGrouped()) {
    var groups = this.getGroups();
    Ext.Array.forEach(groups, function (item, index, allGroups) {
            if (Ext.Array.contains(item.children, record)) {
                grid.getFeature('grouping').expand(item.name);
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user the group field data to expand the group. i have a store grouped by field year.

```
// where this = store
// node = selected row in data store 
// my group field is year
if (this.isGrouped()) {
    var group = psGrid.getView().getFeature('grouping');
    group.expand(node.data.year);
}
```

Comment: Very clean solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using [Ext.ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery) ? This relies on the `xtype` attribute of the components. This is much better than relying on CSS selectors, and it is also much more powerful, since it leverages the Ext component architecture.

I cannot give you code, I'm still learning extjs.

Comment: It's not so much about the query MECHANISM (I just know selecting by CSS class is fragile) as it is "what's the right way to find the group that a row belongs to?".

Comment: Yes, your right, selecting by css is fragile. That's why I'd rather select using xtype, which is secure. It is certainly better than selecting by css, but I cannot tell you if it is the best way.

Comment: @jkyoutsey I see you edited your question and provided an even better solution.